# FPDF extension writetag.ext for Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, fpdf

I am trying to convert a FPDF extension to Classic Asp. I have installed FPDF for Classic Asp on our server (please no flame war regarding why we still use classic ASP). It works well for all that I have tried. Now I want to have the functionality of WriteTag.php as posted on GitHub under by CREACION DE HORARIOS.

In converting the php code I run into trouble with foreach(this.PileStyle as xval) in the function code below.

I have no idea where "this.PileStyle" comes from.  It is this line that gives trouble, which at this time I can't describe, other than that the browser throws the "500 - Internal server error".

Note: there is more to this function, but the foreach shown in the code below is where the error first shows up.  My testing so far involves adding small pieces of code to the "writetag.ext" file until an error shows up.  I have worked on being able to get the extension loaded in when my "writetag.asp" file starts, until the error appeared. I have not been able to progress to and functional tests.

I have searched both, the PHP and the Classic ASP libraries for FPDF, and find no occurance of help for Classic ASP in this regard.

Any help, or instructions how to proceed, will be greatly appreciated.

```
this.FindStyle=function FindStyle(tag, ind) //Inheritance from parent elements
{
     tag=trim(tag);

     // Family
     if(this.TagStyle[tag]["family"]!="")
          family=this.TagStyle[tag]["family"];
     else
     {
          foreach(this.PileStyle as val)
          {
               val=trim(val);
               if(this.TagStyle[val]["family"]!="") 
            {
                   family=this.TagStyle[val]["family"];
                  break;
               }
          }
     }
```

Comment: From what I can tell PileStyle is an array, and in the original code, the pointer is moved to the first element, and then a do while is conducted comparing a list to the PileStyle contents. I would look through your iis logs and get more detail on the error you are experiencing, my guess it has something to do with this array.

Comment: @carmen nuccio:  Your suggestion is well taken.  I have been looking for this PileStyle, and had no success so far.  However it must be there.  Based on your comment I need to look more firmly at some code that builds this list as a global array.  I have been offline (disk crash) for a while, but wouldn't you know, as soon as I am up and running I get an email.  Yours.  Thanks for your comment.